# How to show image sequences as video clip on python

Tags: python, image, sequence

I have a fold with a list of images which are frames extracting from a video clip. I wonder how I can sequentially play the image sequence just as the clip. (Hmm, FPS doesn't matter.)
Checking `PIL` module and `skimage` module, seems that no way I can do it on Python, unless I convert the `JPG` sequence into `GIF` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the animation capability of the matplotlib library. Here is an example copy/pasted from the [online documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An animated image
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation 

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)


fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(f(x, y))

def updatefig(*args):
    global x,y
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x,y))
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Few things to note are:

- each image as to be converted to a numpy array
- use `im.set_array` (in the `updatefig` function) to load the next image